# Data fetching taking so much time in orientdb

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2

In Orientdb when I am running queries on Server for 100000 records and i have to fetch some thousands records,it's taking so much time .
in my case to fetch 600 records, 6 minutes taken by orientdb.
please suggest me what am i doing wrong with my queries.
Select From Complaint_Detail where Complaint_ID in(Select Complaint_Id from Complaint where State='CA') limit 100
for the above query it takes 48 sec.
please help me to find solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Do you have an index against `Complaint.State`? In this way the lookup is much faster.
2. You're using OrientDB as a Relational DBMS, while you should create a link to the records instead of storing the IDs.In this case if you create a property `details` as a set of links to the `Complaint_Detail` class, the query would be much easier to write and fast `select expand(details) from Complaint where State='CA'`

Comment: Thanks Lvca....
i need one more help form you....for the below structure of graph
A------>B--------->C-------->D
now from a query i want to fetch properties of A and D ...
How i can do that.....??

Comment: The best way is then using the pattern matching, it makes your life easier. Take a look at: http://orientdb.com/pattern-matching-with-orientdb/

Comment: ---Hi Lvca i posted a question on stackoverflow.could yoi please look into it.i need your help     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49027672/how-to-load-a-huge-csv-file-in-orient-db