# How to load a huge CSV file in orient db

Tags: etl, orientdb, orientdb2.2, orientdb-etl

I want to load a huge CSV file in my orient Db database.there is some checklist for the database ,that should our db follows.

1- there would be a single csv file and this CSV file will have millions of records and more then 20 Columns.

2- From this csv i have to create multiple Classes and each class will have different Properties (is it possible with Orient db).

3- i have to create index too

Please help for this.how should i create Etl config file for this

Thanks in advance.
please let me know if any input required from my side.

Comment: @Alessandro Rota ,@lvca please help

Comment: Hi @Kunal, have you tried to disable the wal, enable txLog and usebatching ?